# How do I assign value to a new variable from another variable's value in SAS

Tags: sas

So I create a new database called `sitesweb2` from another one called `sitesweb` because I just want to keep certain variables. Those are only binary variables.

Then I want to create a new variable called `fonction` which will take:

- Value 1 when there is a 1 in the M N O P Q R S T U variables.
- Value 2 when there is a 1 in the AA AB AC AD AE AF AG AH AI AJ variables.
- Value 3 when there is a 1 in the AK AL variables.

I have the following code but it doesn't create the `fonction` variable:

```
Data DEV1.SITESWEB2;
set DEV1.SITESWEB ; 
keep INDUSTRIE M N O P Q R S T U AA AB AC AD AE AF AG AH AI AJ AK AL ;
if M or N or O or P or Q or R or S or T or U in ('1') then fonction = 1 ;
else if AA or AB or AC or AD or AE or AF or AG or AH or AI or AJ in ('1') then fonction = 2;
else if AK or AL in ('1') then fonction = 3;
run;
```

What is wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Needs operator/right operand for each variable. It's not meeting the condition:-

```
If M='1' or N='1' or ... then fonction=1;
```

If they were number variables you could add them up in a sum function:

```
if sum(M,N,...)>=1 then...
```

but apparently they are text variables rather than actual binary (number) variables.

Incidentally I'm sure you could also use a `%do` loop and an `asc()`  function within a `%sysfunc()` passing the appropriate ascii numbers to iterate through the alphabet variables and then pass the results as macro variables into the datastep to automate building the if. It requires a bit more effort but if you're repeatedly running this, it's a more elegant solution.

Hope this helps,

Phil

Answer (score 0):

Check for `'1'` in the result of concatenating an array that references the variables.

```
array _1_vars M N O P Q R S T U;
array _2_vars AA AB AC AD AE AF AG AH AI AJ;
array _3_var3 AK AL;

select;
  when (index(cats(of _1_vars(*),'1') then fonction = '1';
  when (index(cats(of _2_vars(*),'1') then fonction = '2';
  when (index(cats(of _3_vars(*),'1') then fonction = '3';
  otherwise ;
end;
```

This will work for both character and numeric variables.  The variables of an array must all be of the same type.

Answer (score 0):

To check if a value appears in a list of variables you can use the WHICH() or WHICHC() function.  It will return the number of the variable where it is first found.  If not found it will return zero.  SAS treats 0 as false and any other number as true.

```
data DEV1.SITESWEB2;
  set DEV1.SITESWEB ;
  keep INDUSTRIE M N O P Q R S T U AA AB AC AD AE AF AG AH AI AJ AK AL ;
  if whichc('1', of M N O P Q R S T U) then fonction = 1 ;
  else if whichc('1', of AA AB AC AD AE AF AG AH AI AJ) then fonction = 2;
  else if whichc('1', of AK AL) then fonction = 3;
  keep fonction ;
run;
```

Make sure to KEEP your new variable.